# Function is returning false even the condition is true why?

Tags: javascript

```
function checkform(for1)
{ 
   var result=checkform1(for1);
   alert(result);
}
function checkform1(form)
{
    var valid=false;
    var val1 = document.getElementById('security_code').value;
    $.get(url, function(data) {
        if(data.toString()==val1.toString())
        {
            var elem = document.getElementById("captchaerr");
            elem.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            valid=true;
        }
        else
        {
            var elem = document.getElementById("captchaerr");
            elem.style.visibility = 'visible';
            valid=false;
        }           
    }); 
    return valid;
}
```

result alert is always false even the condtion(data.toString()==val1.toString()) is true
how the control passes in this.
thnks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your 'get' ajax call is an async one, you can use a callback to get the result:

```
function checkform(for1)
{ 
   checkform1(for1, function(result) //provide the callback to the async function
   {
     alert(result); 
   });      
}
function checkform1(form, callback)
{
    var valid=false;
    var val1 = document.getElementById('security_code').value;
    $.get(url, function(data) 
    {
        if(data.toString()==val1.toString())
        {
            var elem = document.getElementById("captchaerr");
            elem.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            valid=true;
        }
        else
        {
            var elem = document.getElementById("captchaerr");
            elem.style.visibility = 'visible';
            valid=false;
        }           
        if(callback)
            callback(valid);// call the callback INSIDE of the complete callback of the 'get' jquery function
    }); 

}
```

Comment: This suffers from the same problem as the OP's code.  The `callback` needs to be called inside the `$.get` not after it.

Comment: good point  Rocket, I have just edited ... thanks ! it seems that I need more light in here .

Comment: how could I get the result outside the checkform1 but inside the checkform so that i can return it to onsubmit,thnks.

Comment: @Irfan: You cannot return a value from an AJAX call, it doesn't work that way.  You need to have all the logic in the callback function.

Answer (score 2):

By default $.get aka Ajax.get is asynchronous (it runs in the background). So your function "checkform1" is returning before the Ajax request finishes and sets the "valid" variable.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't** use toString(), as string.[toString()](http://jsfiddle.net/) will return `string`. Just test `data == val1`.

Answer (score 1):

You are making a asynchronous call, so if you want to check for the result then you have to do this inside the callback

```
 function checkform1(form)
{
    var valid=false;
    var val1 = document.getElementById('security_code').value;
    $.get(url, function(data) {
        if(data.toString()==val1.toString())
        {
        var elem = document.getElementById("captchaerr");
        elem.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        valid=true;
        }
        else
        {
        var elem = document.getElementById("captchaerr");
        elem.style.visibility = 'visible';
        valid=false;
        }      
        //here you will get the valid and 
        //not outside...outside it will be always false.
    }); 

    //This line will be executed immediately after the previous line
    // and will not wait for the call to complete, so this needs to be done 
    // in the callback. 
    return valid;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just before condition put alert on both values alert(val1 + '---' + data) and see if its exactly same .

Also trim them before comparing just in case it has some padding to it.